# Flask + curl: Trigger a specific route with a POST request

Tags: python-3.x, flask, curl, post

I wrote a small flask server. I tried to handle POST parameters.
This is the snippet, for the route that handles that POST request.

```
@app.route('/convert', methods=['POST'])
def convert_Me():
    conversion_item = request.args.get('item')
    conversion_method = request.args.get('method')
    print(conversion_item)
    print(conversion_method)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

The server runs on `127.0.0.1:5000`

I tried to test this with:

```
curl -X POST --data "item=myitem&method=MyMethod" 127.0.0.1/convert:5000
```

and also

```
curl --data "item=myitem&method=MyMethod" 127.0.0.1/convert:5000
```

However, i got this error message back:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

I don't want to connect to port 80 though. I want port 5000, and i specified that.

So how am i going to make curl send the parameters to my server on that route?

EDIT: Tried again both approaches with the solution Mindslave provided. However, it still does not work.

This is what i get on the curl terminal:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="/">/</a>.  If not click the link.
```

And this is what i get on the flask server terminal:

```
None
None
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2021 16:18:41] "POST /convert HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

EDIT 2: This is the full code of the server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import shortuuid

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    uuid_name = shortuuid.uuid() + ".step"
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    if uploaded_file.filename != '':
        #uploaded_file.save(uploaded_file.filename)
        uploaded_file.save(uuid_name)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/convert', methods=['POST'])
def convert_STEP():
    #first things first. i gotta send two params (filename and conversion type) with curl and print them here
    conversion_item = request.args.get('item')
    conversion_method = request.args.get('method')
    print(conversion_item)
    print(conversion_method)
    return redirect(url_for('index')) # remove later
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`127.0.0.1/convert:5000` is the wrong way around, you need to use the port before the path `127.0.0.1:5000/convert`

You also need to change your request method to access post data, `request.args.get('item')` is for url parameter, but what you are sending is post data, thus you should use `request.form.get('item')`

Comment: i had some progress but still it does not work. I updated the question. Please take a look...

Comment: I also added the complete code of the server, if that is helpful to you.

Comment: I see you are using `request.args` but post data is part of `request.form`, thus conversion_item = request.args.get('item') should be conversion_item = request.form.get('item')